# logging in ant script for running .sql

Tags: sql, oracle, ant, plsql

I have a .sql file which contain create script for 20 tables.I am running this through ant.

the Ant Script is

```
<target name="CompleteDBRollCreate" >
        <sql classpath="D:\lib\ojdbc14.jar"      driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"     
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@12326:1521:orcl"      
        userid="scott"      password="tiger"    
        src="D:\dropalltables.sql"  /> 
        </target>
```

but there is no logging in ant so I can't know if the SQL file was executed correctly. Can any one please suggest how to do logging into a separate localfile/on the ant console. I just want to know where I need to change the .sql file or the ant script.

Answer (score 2):

There is logging in ant. [Check out Running Apache Ant - Command Line](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html):

> -logfile         use given file for log

Answer (score 1):

-logfile will give you jdbc jdbc exceptions and all the noise around that, which can be useful, but I would also recommend spooling in the sql file as well as it looks like you are going to have multiple statements in the script. So I'd say you should use the -logfile option and also alter your script to spool any ORA errors you might encounter if you have multiple statements.

```
spool test.out
create table foo (testCol varchar2(2));

drop table foo;

spool off
```

Comment: @nihkil :           I tried in@janarde way but the problem is that through ant when i am connecting to db and calling the sql file ,In that sql file setting the spool command ad suggested by you.but it throughing error stating nvalid sql statement because it thinks that both the create script and spool are of only one statement.

Comment: yep sorry, you are absolutely right. It will not work using just a sql task. Should have been paying more attention. You could use incanto to invoke a sqlplus session and then use spooling. Sorry for the confusion. information on Incanto can be found here: http://incanto.sourceforge.net/best-practices.html